# Cannot find symbol error for key

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to compile my code but I get an error stating `cannot find symbol - variable key`.  I'm trying to decrypt a message from my files, and can't seem to get the right void method to run all this code. I'm hoping figuring out this small problem will lead to me being able to run my code properly, and get the decryption/encryption correct. Note: any suggestions on how to develop a void testing method would be greatly appreciated. Just that I'm focused on why I get this error message first and foremost. It's on this line `this.encrypt_key = key;`.

```
public class CaesarCipherTwo {
    private int encrypt_key = 0;
    private int key1 = -1;
    private int key2 = -1;
    private CaesarCipher cc1;
    private CaesarCipher cc2;


    /**
     * Constructor - Takes in the two keys used for encryption. Use this constructor when you want to use this object for encryption (& then subsequent 
     * decryption of same string)
     * 
     * @param key1
     *              Key1 used in encryption process
     * @param key2
     *              Key2 used in encryption process
     */


    public CaesarCipherTwo(int key1, int key2){

        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
        cc1 = new CaesarCipher();

        cc2 = new CaesarCipher();


    }
     private void generateEncryptionLookup(){
        String alphabet_uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String alphabet_lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   

        String e_alphabet_uppercase = alphabet_uppercase.substring(encrypt_key) + alphabet_uppercase.substring(0,encrypt_key);
        String e_alphabet_lowercase = alphabet_lowercase.substring(encrypt_key) + alphabet_lowercase.substring(0,encrypt_key);


        String alphabet = alphabet_uppercase + alphabet_lowercase;
        String e_alphabet = e_alphabet_uppercase + e_alphabet_lowercase;
    }
    private String set_key;
    public void set_key(String set_key) {

        this.encrypt_key = key;
        this.generateEncryptionLookup();
        cc1.set_key(key1);
        cc2.set_key(key2);
    }
    public String decryptString(int mode){

        int key = -1;
        int current_key = this.get_key();

        if (mode == 1){
            key = 26 - encrypt_key;

        } else if (mode == 2){
            this.get_char_freq();
            key = this.compute_shift(this.get_max_char_freq());

        }

        this.set_key(key); //this statement internally mutates the key which is not a good idea

        String decryptedString = this.encryptString();
        this.set_key(current_key); //this statement reverts the state of the Caesar Cipher
        return decryptedString;

    }
    /**
     * Constructor - To be used when you want to use this class for decryption & the method needs to figure out the decryption keys
     */
    public CaesarCipherTwo(){
        cc1 = new CaesarCipher();
        cc2 = new CaesarCipher();
    }

    /**
     * Takes a String as input and encrypts it using 2 keys
     * @param s 
     *          Input String
     * @return
     *          Encrypted String
     */

    public String encrypt(String s){
        cc1.set_string_under_action(s);
        cc2.set_string_under_action(s);
        String encrypted1 = cc1.encryptString();
        String encrypted2 = cc2.encryptString();
        String encrypted = CaesarCipher.interleave(encrypted1, encrypted2);
        return encrypted;

    }

    /**
     * Takes a String and decrypts it using 2 keys
     * @param s
     *          String input for decryption
     * @param mode
     *          Accepts either 1 or 2 as input
     *          Mode 1 - Use the complement of key used for encryption while doing decryption. Its critical that this mode be used with the same
     *                   key settings as used while encrypting the String
     *          Mode 2 - The method figures out the right decryption key to be used 
     * @return
     *          Decrypted String
     */

    public String decrypt(String s, int mode){

        String [] decrypt = CaesarCipherTwo.halfOfString(s);
        cc1.set_string_under_action(decrypt[0]);
        cc2.set_string_under_action(decrypt[1]);
        String d1 = cc1.decryptString(mode);
        String d2 = cc2.decryptString(mode);
        String d = CaesarCipherTwo.weaveTwoStrings(d1, d2);
        return d;   
    }

    /**
     * Break a string into 2 (alternate chars in each of the 2 resultant strings)
     * @param s 
     *          Input String
     * @return
     *          Returns an array of 2 strings. These are the resultant strings from breaking the input string
     */

    public static String[] halfOfString(String s){
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(10000);
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(10000);
        String [] decrypt = new String[2];

        for (int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
            if (i%2 == 0){
                sb1.append(s.charAt(i));
            }else {
                sb2.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        decrypt[0] = sb1.toString();
        decrypt[1] = sb2.toString();
        return decrypt;
    }

    /**
     * This method weaves 2 strings together into a single string. Letters from each of the input strings form alternate letters in final string
     * @param s1
     *          First input String
     * @param s2
     *          Second input String
     * @return
     *          Final resultant String
     */

    public static String weaveTwoStrings(String s1,String s2){
        int len = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);

            for (int i=0; i< len; i++){
                if (i < s1.length() && i < s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
                }else if (i < s1.length() && i >= s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
                }else if (i >= s1.length() && i < s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(i)); 
                }
            }        
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: there's no instance or local variable for `set_key()` to use here `this.encrypt_key = key;`

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

At this point

```
private String set_key;
public void set_key(String set_key) {

    this.encrypt_key = key;     <<<*** "key" not defined here
    this.generateEncryptionLookup();
    cc1.set_key(key1);
    cc2.set_key(key2);
}
```

You have not defined a variable named `key`.

Comment: No, that answer gives me this error: `incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int`

Comment: Well, he problem is still that you haven't defined `key`

Comment: I thought having this.encrypt_key assigned to key would be sufficient.

Comment: Assignment goes right to left.  That statement attempts to assign the (undefined) value of `key` to `this.encrypt_key`.  There's something missing in your understanding of what's going on, but I can't figure it out.